# Angular 2 drop down list not populating

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I'm trying to create a dropdown list with options for an Enum. However the dropdown never seems to get populated with values. It appears to hold the expected number of values but they are all what appears to be blank strings.

In the constructor for the component I pupulate an array of strings with the values from the Enum:

```
var values = Object.keys(BoCustomSelectionGroupingType);
      this.options = values.slice(values.length / 2);

      console.log(this.options);
```

When theres are logged to the broswer console I do see the expected values.

However when I try populate a HTML dropdown with the values they do not appear

```
<div>
    <select>
       <option *ngFor="let name of options">{{name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I've tried many different options for achieving this including piping with enums but I always seem to run into this issue of the correct number of values in the dropdown but what appears to be empty strings or objects.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've also tried to move the initialization into the ngOnInit() method for the component but this also does not work. It no no longer displays any items in the dropdown.

Comment: the best way for us to help you is if you can make a working example and give us the link.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/g77hh4UKBCTg6kHkQPUD?p=preview

Comment: It seems to work correctly and as expected in this plunker. Perhaps some other part of my code is interfering with it. :-/

Comment: Do you have any console errors? because as you stated and by seeing plunker it is working.

Comment: I had several errors which I have managed to remove. Now the values are appearing in the dropdown list but I can only see the text when I am hovering over it.

Comment: one error still remains Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js. I tired to follow some stack overflow threads on solving this but haven't managed so far. Will continue to try.

Comment: The uncaught Error is a message from the Bootstrap 4 dropdown. It needs the js-library popper.js. popper.js replaces tether.js.
If you work with bootstrap 4 take a look at https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Comment: yes, the error simply says, ur missing the js library.